# Portable downloader for Windows 10

Tags: windows, portable, download-manager

I'm looking for a download manager that can be run as a simple executable from a folder in an external drive plugged into a Windows 10 computer, run as an unprivileged user.
The use case is that I want to load it with a list of downloads at home (where I connect to the internet through a metered cell connection) and run the actual downloading from this other computer that has broadband, so that the files are stored in a folder path relative to the program's, or one that I choose for the session.

I'm mainly interested in standard protocols like HTTP and FTP. As a secondary priority, file sharing sites, such as MEGA, GDrive, Dropbox, etc. And as a prescindible third, P2P.
I prefer open source.

Comment: Hello, you shouldn't post comments as answers. Also, you hjaven't mentioned GUI in your question, which should be as detailed as possible. How should it exactly work, load a txt file with URLs to download?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [wget](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). It can download from list of URLs like this:

```
wget -i list_file
```

It support HTTP, FTP URLs. For other protocols you can check [curl](https://curl.se/windows/)